# Symfony3 ignore folder that has WordPress within the same website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony

We are working on a project using Symfony 3. We have a folder within the same project that we want to call "blog" and we want to host a WordPress instance in that folder that will work independently from the other part of the system but under the same domain, so ideally I will have:

`www.domain.com/` (and any URL under that domain) for the entire system
`www.domain.com/blog/` for the entire WordPress blog which is not interconnected with the other part of the FrontEnd of the system.

I have tried escape the folder using things like this in the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|blog|assets)
```

This used to work for me in Symfony2, however, with Symfony3 due to the structure changes this is no longer working for me anymore.

Any advice?

Comment: not much changed with regards to structure, only var/app/bin folder changes really.  Are you sure its something to do with that?  the thought of putting a wordpress site inside a symfony one makes me itch.....

Comment: why dont you move the "blog" folder to web/ ?